# SocialAuth 4.3 does not work for GooglePlus

Tags: socialauth

I am using SocialAuth v4.3 java library for providing social login functionality. It works for Google, Facebook but doesnt work for Google-plus. I am getting following error:

```
org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthConfig - Configuration for provider googleplus is not available
```

Any clue on how to fix this? Another problem is login with Google does not provide date of birth, location. Is it possible to get this information?

Answer (score -1):

1) you have to specify credentials for `Google+` authorization.

Create `assets/oauth_consumer.properties` file with

```
googleapis.com.consumer_key=YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY
googleapis.com.consumer_secret=SECRET
```

**or** add credentials programmatically

```
socialAuthAdapter.addConfig(SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, SECRET, null /*permissions*/);
```

2) `callback url` should be specified in `SocialAuthAdapter`

```
socialAuthAdapter.addCallBack(SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, "PLACE_YOUR_URL_HERE");
```

How to create `callback url` (aka. `redirect_uri`) you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/redirect-uri-flow)

3) specify response listener

```
socialAuthAdapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

private class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle bundle) {
        final String providerName = bundle.getString(SocialAuthAdapter.PROVIDER);
        String accessToken = socialAuthAdapter.getCurrentProvider().getAccessGrant().getKey();
        // login to your server using accessToken, or make calls to google+ API using this token
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final SocialAuthError socialAuthError) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
    }
}
```

I had also problems with login, and problem was in incorrect `redirect_uri`. Read more about `oauth2` [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp?hl=ru)

Answer (score -1):

Use API`s provided by Google and Facebook instead of the SocialAuth. They are much simple and easy to integrate. I have wasted a lot of time using this SocialAuth and dont want you guys to  do the same.

Comment: "you just can not cook"